# Write caption with picked image

Tags: flutter

I am looking for a Flutter component that will allow me to pick an image from mobile library and write caption similar to what you would see in chat apps.  Is there any Flutter component that can help with that.  I can use PickerImage widget but it does not support writing caption with the image.

I could my own component but that requires reading images from the mobile library and compressing the image.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Use this **Camera** package](https://pub.dev/packages/camera/install)

[Also you can refer this code](https://github.com/DevStack06/Whatsapp-Clone-Flutter/blob/master/lib/Screens/CameraScreen.dart)

code to select image from gallery

```
 PickedFile pickedFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
    maxWidth: 1800,
    maxHeight: 1800,
);
```

Full code link : [link](https://educity.app/flutter/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-and-display-it-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am not interested in taking a picture with camera.  I am interested in picking an image, compress it, add label to it.

Comment: you can do the same with this package

Comment: how can you list all images in you mobile using this library?

Comment: i have edited my answer...this might help you